# Capture route with # Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a site that uses a guard to stop unauthenticated access and direct to a login page. I want to be able to capture the route before I redirect to the login page, save it to local storage, and after the user authenticates, load the route from local storage and route navigate to it. I need the entire route with Paramus, for example

Website.com/#/app/review/27

Is this possible?

Comment: Storing the route from urltree, read it and use router.navigateByUrl should work I reckon.

Comment: Do you have a sample? When I use URL tree , I don't get anything after #

Comment: Ah. Apply the KISS rule and do it vanillastyle: let route = location.href.split('#')[1]; // will give /app/review/27.